# Sending multiple string using TCP goes too quick how do I await?

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, listbox, async-await

So I am trying to send all the items I have in my Listbox to a server that has another Listbox.
I cant access the code to the server all I can do is connect and send strings to it.

So what I have done so far is that I have connected to it and I can send single strings without any issues, now when I try to send all the items in the listbox  it does it so fast that some strings get send as 1 package if that makes any sense.

Picture a list like this

```
Joss
Nota
Pioneer
PRB
Python
Tomcar
Toyota
```

What happends when I send from client to the server is that the server recieves it like this

```
Joss
Nota
PioneerPRBPython
Tomcar
Toyota
```

Because It's sending way too fast. 
How would I make it go slower? I want to use async and await but not sure how to.

```
private void SendAll()
        {
            foreach (string Book in lbMain.Items)
            {
                string[] splitter = Book.Split(new string[] { "###" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                Book aBook = new Book();

                aBook.Title = splitter[0];
                aBook.Author = splitter[1];
                aBook.Genre = splitter[2];

                if (splitter.Length < 4)
                    aBook.IsAvailable = null;
                else
                    aBook.IsAvailable = Convert.ToBoolean(splitter[3]);





                //Create a network stream to get all the data that comes and goes through the client.
                NetworkStream nwStream = Client.GetStream();

                //Convert out string message to a byteArray because we will send it as a buffer later. 
                //IMPORTANT UNICODE BECAUSE .net uses utf8 by default
                //
                byte[] bytesToSend = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(aBook.ToString());

                //Write out to the console what we are sending.
                Console.WriteLine("Sending: " + aBook.ToString());

                //Use the networkstream to send the byteArray we just declared above, start at the offset of zero, and the size of the packet we are sending is the size of the messages length.
                nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

                //Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
```

Comment: "IMPORTANT UNICODE BECAUSE .net uses utf8 by default" - that's not really true; some APIs might use utf8 as their default encoding, but .net is mostly utf-16 focused, as an internal implementation detail

Answer (score 2):

The problem here isn't speed, and slowing it down is bad. The problem is that TCP is a *stream protocol* - there is no expectation that the bytes you send match *send vs receive* in terms of size of individual operations. All that is guaranteed is that the same byte sequence will arrive in the same order. Instead, you need to implement a "frame" protocol - i.e. some mechanism to distinguish separate items. Since you're using text, a very pragmatic option is to terminate each with a CRLF. The server should read until it has a CRLF (i.e. a full frame) then interprets those bytes.

In binary protocols, length-prefix is more common than a terminator (sentinel) value.

[Related reading](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2013/02/how-many-ways-can-you-mess-up-io.html)

Comment: Hm.. Works just fine when letting it sleep inbetween sending the packets.. https://i.imgur.com/oedtcfD.gif

Comment: @TheHappyGuy and a car with a broken radiator works just fine when letting it sleep inbetween very short journeys. What I'm saying is: your approach is fundamentally broken, and right now you're using an *unreliable side-effect* of timing - a forced race condition, essentially - as a hack. The fix is to correctly implement framing.

Comment: How would I use framing?

Comment: @TheHappyGuy literally what I said the answer; it doesn't need to be complicated - simply adding a CRLF (`\r\n` in C# string literal syntax) after each entry is enough; the server then knows where each entry ends; in network terminology: each chunk of bytes terminated by a CRLF can be interpreted as a "frame". Note that "framing" can take different forms, depending on what is needed - it isn't *always* CRLF-related. Just: that would work fine here.

Comment: Oh! I thought CRLF was something else like maybe a class of some sort, thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: @TheHappyGuy nope; simply a line terminator - "carriage return / line feed"